# liquibase CDATA in insert

Tags: java, liquibase

Is it somehow possible to write xml/json data as CDATA in liquibase programatically?
This is my method with which I'm writing changelog.

```
private static void writeCommandToLiquibaseChangelog(String command) {
        DatabaseChangeLog changeLog = new DatabaseChangeLog();
        ChangeSet changeSet = new ChangeSet("1", "tester", false, false, null, /* specify env ?*/ null, null, changeLog);

        Column column = new Column("payload");
        ColumnConfig columnConfig = new ColumnConfig(column);
        columnConfig.setValue(command);

        InsertDataChange insert = new InsertDataChange();
        insert.setTableName("dc_command_initializer");
        insert.setColumns(Arrays.asList(columnConfig));

        changeSet.addChange(insert);
        changeLog.addChangeSet(changeSet);

        try (OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            XMLChangeLogSerializer xmlChangeLogSerializer = new XMLChangeLogSerializer();
            xmlChangeLogSerializer.write(changeLog.getChangeSets(), baos);
            System.out.println(baos.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I've tried to do something like `columnConfig.setValue("<![CDATA[" + command + "]]>");` but that didn't helped me.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<column name="payload"><![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <test>this is test value</test> ]]>  </column>
```

Comment: What happend when you used columnConfig.setValue("<![CDATA[" + command + "]]>");? From the documentation of liquibase: ColumnConfig.setValue " This method does no processing of the string.". So it should just put your provided string into the value.

Comment: This is the output: ```<column name="payload" value="&lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;  &lt;test&gt;this is test value&lt;/test&gt;]]&gt;"/>```. In fact this doesn't affect the final data inside database. But I'd like to have changelog readable for other users.

Comment: You should probably put in a feature request for this. (and maybe also ask them to update their documentation to say not say this method does no processing).